# Image loading issue when using dvips

Tags: graphics, dvips

when I moved the dvips from the `usepackage`, the image loaded but the margin will be reduced. If I kept the dvips, the image does not show on the paper.

***the code in thesis.tex is***

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}            
\usepackage{rotating}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage[scriptsize]{caption} 

\usepackage[setpagesize=false]{hyperref}

\hyphenation{a-gen-tiz-za-zio-ne}

\setlength{\paperwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\paperheight}{24cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin} {2. cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin} {2. cm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin} {-0.4 cm}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin} {-0.4 cm}
\linespread{1.1}

\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\normalfont \sffamily \itshape \small}


\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\include{cover}
\thispagestyle{empty} \normalfont \cleardoublepage
\include{dedication}
\thispagestyle{empty}  \cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty} \vspace*{.75truecm} \cleardoublepage
\include{thanks}
\thispagestyle{empty} \vspace*{.75truecm} \normalfont \cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{plain}\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}         
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}    

\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}    
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}     
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt} 

\tableofcontents


\include{capitolo1}
\include{capitolo2}
\include{chapter3}

\cleardoublepage
% ---- Bibliography ----
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}
%\nocite{*}

\appendix

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyfoot{}                                               
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\appendixname\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}         
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}    

\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}    
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}     
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt} 

\end{document}
```

***and code in cover.tex is***

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
%\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{-1.5cm} \bfseries{
\begin{center}
  \large
  POLITECNICO DI MILANO\\
  \normalsize
  Corso di Laurea MAGISTRALE in Ingegneria Informatica\\
  Dipartimento di Elettronica e Informazione\\
  \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{./pictures/logopm}
%   \psfig{file=./pictures/logopm.jpg,width=3.5cm}
    \end{center}
  \end{figure}
  \vspace*{0.3cm} \LARGE



  \textbf{Analysis of Different Footprints for JPEG Compression Detection}\\



  \vspace*{.75truecm} \large

\end{center}
\vspace*{3.0cm} \large
\begin{flushleft}


  Supervisor: Prof.Paolo Bestagini \\
  Associate Supervisor: Dr.Luca Bondi

\end{flushleft}
\vspace*{1.0cm}
\begin{flushright}


  Tesi di Laurea di:\\ Chen Ke, matricola 833240 \\ 



\end{flushright}
\vspace*{0.5cm}
\begin{center}



  Anno Accademico 2016-2017
\end{center} \clearpage
}
```

Comment: you do not say but presumably you are not using latex and dvips but pdflatex? in which case remove the dvips option and then set whatever page size/margins you need using the geometry package.

Comment: I think that at least knowing which engine are you using is in order...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I used \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx} and image does not display, if dvips removed, the margin will be reduced. The paper size is A4, and I set the /setlength(/paperwidth=16cm,/paperheight=24cm,/oddsidemargin=/evensidemargin=2cm), /addtolength(/oddsidemargin=/evensidemargin=-0.4)

Comment: but you have not said what program you are using to typeset the document (nor shown any usable code) if you are not using latex+dvips do not use the dvips option otherwise nothing will work. If th epage margins are wrong then the simplest way to fix them is using the geometry package as I said above.   i can not guess what you mean by `/setlength(/paperwidth=16cm,/paperheight=24cm,/oddsidemargin‌​=/evensidemargin=2cm‌​), /addtolength(/oddsidemargin=/evensidemargin=-0.4)` as it isn't tex syntax at all

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry...I'm a beginner and I use TexStudio, the code is \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\paperheight}{24cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin} {2. cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin} {2. cm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin} {-0.4 cm}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin} {-0.4 cm}
\linespread{1.1}

\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\normalfont \sffamily \itshape \small}
\pagestyle{empty}

Comment: @Chan, please move code from your comment to question!

Comment: @Zarko moved to question

Comment: @Chan Thanks for adding the code to your question, but please can you replace the images with copyable code? We don't want to retype everything. And can you please answer the questions which tex engine you are using?

Comment: @samcarter pdflatex

Comment: @Chan That's just the TeX distribution. We need to know if you are using `latex`, `pdflatex` or something else to compile. If your paper is A4 then the height is 297mm and the width is 210mm, so I don't know why you would set it to 240 x 160 mm

Comment: @cfr use pdflatex

Comment: So you can't use the `dvips` option if you compile with `pdflatex`. `dvips` is for cases where you are using `dvips` and not where you are using `pdftex`.

Answer (score 2):

`dvips` is no option to be used with `pdflatex`, simply remove it.

With your specific document, this means that now your setting for paperwidth, margins etc. are taken into account - so adjust (or remove) these numbers to get back the large margins you are used to from the `dvips` option.